# How do include a .c file to my ios app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, c

I have file.c file that I want to add to my ios app. I renamed it to file.m, rename the main() to main2() and included it in my project in xCode. It compiles fine but how do I run main2()?

Could someone please explain this in detail? Thanks.

Comment: Surely you just call `main2()`, like you would any other method.

Comment: That's what I thought too but it keeps hanging my application at he launch (exactly where my splash screen is). I wonder if I'm doing something wrong. Note: the c file does work and it compiles... just not with my app. :(

Comment: I have voted to close until we get more information... do you know how breakpoints work and the debugger, you should step through to see if the code in main2() is getting executed and if it ever returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More likely than not, the `main` of the original C program is going to try and set up a processing loop or otherwise wait for some kind of input and then try to process it.

You aren't going to be able to simply embed one *entire program* in another and expect it to work unmodified.   You'll need to understand how the second program works and then integrate that functionality into the first.  Without seeing the implementation of your second `main`, it is impossible to say more.

Answer (score 1):

You have to call main2() somewhere in your main source file. main() is the entry point for C programs, so if you rename main() to something else, you will have to call it manually.